# Chart Area Axes - The chart area contains incompatible chart types

Tags: c#-4.0, charts

Getting error

```
Chart Area Axes - The chart area contains incompatible chart types. For example, bar charts and column charts cannot exist in the same chart area.
```

for

```
     Chart Chart1 = FirstChart(dt1);
        Chart Chart2 = CreateChart(dt2);
         Chart1.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        Chart2.SaveImage(stream1, ChartImageFormat.Png);
protected Chart FirstChart(DataTable dtRpt)
        {
            Chart chart = new Chart();
            chart.Height = 800;
            chart.Width = 600;
            chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (ViewState["flag"].ToString() == "true")
            {
                chart = ChartCode(chart, dtRpt, "10");
            }
            else
            {
                dt = GameLib.Reports.SubjectToFill(KidId, Dt1, Dt2, Gradeid);
                if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
                {
                    chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackImage = "~/img/noreport1.png";
                    chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackImageWrapMode = ChartImageWrapMode.Unscaled;
                    chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackImageAlignment = ChartImageAlignmentStyle.Center;
                }
                else
                {
                    chart = ChartCode(chart, dtRpt, "10");
                }
            }


            return chart;
        }

        protected Chart createchart (DataTable dtRpt)
        {
            Chart chart = new Chart();
            chart.Height = 800;
            chart.Width = 600;
            chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");
            chart.Series.Add("Class Average ");
            chart.Series.Add("Score ");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (ViewState["flag"].ToString() == "true")
            {
                chart = ChartCode(chart, dtRpt, "10");
            }
            else
            {
                dt = GameLib.Reports.SubjectToFill(KidId, Dt1, Dt2, Gradeid);
                if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
                {
                    chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackImage = "~/img/noreport1.png";
                    chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackImageWrapMode = ChartImageWrapMode.Unscaled;
                    chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackImageAlignment = ChartImageAlignmentStyle.Center;
                }
                else
                {
                    chart = ChartCode(chart, dtRpt, "10");
                }
            }

            return chart;
        }
          protected Chart ChartCode(Chart chart, DataTable dtRpt, string width)
    {
        if (width == "15")
        {
            chart.Series.Add("Number of games");
            chart.Series.Add("Child Played Count");
        }
        chart.Series.Add("Class Average ");
        chart.Series.Add("Score ");

        for (int i = 0; i < dtRpt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dtRpt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0], dtRpt.Rows[i].ItemArray[4]);
            chart.Series[1].Points.AddXY(dtRpt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0], dtRpt.Rows[i].ItemArray[5]);
            chart.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
            chart.Series[1].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;

            System.Drawing.Color col = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3F66B1");
            System.Drawing.Color col1 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DD3B26");
            chart.Series[0].Color = col;
            chart.Series[1].Color = col1;
        }


        chart.Legends.Add("Legend1");
        chart.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
        chart.Legends[0].Alignment = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
        chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Topics";
        chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Average Score  ";
        if (width == "15")
        {
            chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{#}%";
        }
        chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart.Series[0]["PixelPointWidth"] = width;
        chart.Series[1]["PixelPointWidth"] = width;
        ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"];
        ca.AxisX.LineWidth = 1;
        ca.AxisY.LineWidth = 1;
        ca.AxisX2.LineWidth = 1;
        ca.AxisY2.LineWidth = 1;
        ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
        ca.AxisY.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
        ca.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;
        ca.AxisY.IsMarginVisible = true;
        ca.AxisX.ScaleBreakStyle.LineWidth = 1;
        ca.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.LineWidth = 1;
        ca.AxisX.Interval = 1;
        // ca.AxisY.Interval = 10;
        ca.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        ca.AxisX.Maximum = int.Parse(dtRpt.Rows.Count.ToString()) + 1;
        ca.AxisX.Interval = 1;
        ca.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.StartFromZero = StartFromZero.Yes;
        ca.AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.FixedCount; ca.AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.FixedCount;
        ca.AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
        ca.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = true;
        ca.AxisX.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Auto;
        ca.AxisY.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Auto;
        ca.AxisX.LabelAutoFitMinFontSize = 6;
        ca.AxisY.LabelAutoFitMinFontSize = 6;
        ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
        ca.AxisY.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
        ca.AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Horizontal;
        ca.AxisY.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
        ca.AxisY = new Axis { LabelStyle = new LabelStyle() { Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7.5f) } };
        ca.AxisY.Minimum = 0;

        if (width == "15")
        {
            ca.AxisY.Interval = 25;
            ca.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{#}%";
            ca.AxisY.Maximum = 100;
        }
        return chart;
    }
```

Actually both are bar chart.I dont why this error can anyone help me to resolve this error.Its brief code;Both firstchart and createchart exicutes the create code where i specifes the series type..................................................................................................................

Comment: Post some more code. For example, what do your methods `FirstChart` and `CreateChart` do? Where do you add series to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution myself;
instead of

```
chart.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
chart.Series[1].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
```

replaced with

```
 foreach (Series series in chart.Series)
 {
      series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
 }
```