# How to create a horizontal barchart in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have created the bar chart but the series are showing *vertically*.I need to show the bars *horizontally*.i have used the below code

```
private void LoadChartData(DataTable initialDataSource)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < initialDataSource.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            Series series = new Series();
            foreach (DataRow dr in initialDataSource.Rows)
            {
                int y = (int)dr[i];
                series.Points.AddXY(dr["Closing_Month"].ToString(), y);
            }
            Chart1.Series.Add(series);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your chart type in your `Series` variable.

```
/*Horizontal bars*/
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;

/*Vertical columns*/
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
```

So your code could look like this:

```
private void LoadChartData(DataTable initialDataSource)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < initialDataSource.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        Series series = new Series();
        /*make sure every series is of the same chart type*/
        foreach (Series series in chart.Series)
        {
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        }
        foreach (DataRow dr in initialDataSource.Rows)
        {
            int y = (int)dr[i];
            series.Points.AddXY(dr["Closing_Month"].ToString(), y);
        }
        Chart1.Series.Add(series);
    }
}
```

Reference:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series(v=vs.110).aspx
- [Changing a horizontal bar chart to a vertical one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374862/changing-a-horizontal-bar-chart-to-a-vertical-one)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.charttype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you @Serv.But i have tried that already but its throwing error like cannot include multiple chartypes at the same time

Comment: Chart Area Axes - The chart area contains incompatible chart types. For example, bar charts and column charts cannot exist in the same chart area. this is the error throwed

Comment: This means you have different SeriesChartTypes defined in your chart. I have edited my answer. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244745/chart-area-axes-the-chart-area-contains-incompatible-chart-types

Comment: Yeah.I also fixed that by doing the same code.Thank you for your great help.It was fixed.@Serv